# Symfony 2 or PHP frameworks generally and complicated forms/subforms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am a Zend Framework user and I am searching for some alternatives. I was interested in Symfony in the past.

I have recently written some really complicated forms, that was UX idea in my company to make it possible to edit a survey on one page.

**Survey consists of:**

- Survey has many Steps
- Steps has many Questions
- Questions have many Answers

So as you can see it was woking with 4 connected models. Each model was represented by subform. I could add steps/questions/answers via ajax.

Of course I had to write a lot of custom code, eg. when populating data sent via POST to form I needed to create subforms and populate them, but all logic stayed in form objects. For controller that was transparent. All I need to do in controller was populating form with POST or with Database Survey Row object and it was working.

I am wondering how I can acomplish that in symfony2?

After reading that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html I think that would be really hard.

**Can someone briefly describe how to acomplish this?**

How to create subforms dynamically and append them to form in symfony? Can subforms have other subforms like my survey->step->question->answer connection?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to embed a collection of forms if that will work for your situation. http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html